# Windows to Go Stuck in "Preparing Automatic Repair"

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-10-v1903, windows-to-go

My hard disk crashed (Running Enterprise Windows, original) and ever since, I have been running Windows to Go from my 128GB SanDisk pen drive smoothly - till last week, after I booted into the pen drive from a different system in an emergency situation.

It worked perfect then - with scaled down graphics et al. Then I shut it down properly, I inserted it a day later in my laptop - which booted normal until I tried to log in - it restarted with BSoD,and is stuck in "Preparing Automatic Repair" ever since - won't even move a bit (I tried keeping it alive overnight, of no use.)

Things I tried:

1. Tried booting from another Windows and checked around.
2. Tried to run SFC from another install, it said "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service"
3. Tried chkdsk, after which I am not even able to boot into Windows.
4. Tried booting into Windows Install Image, and get into recovery options, doesn't recognise Windows to Go as a Windows Install.

Is there any way to resurrect the Windows now?

Comment: You probably need to replace the internal drive first. Then you can install Windows normally.

Comment: That I am aware of - can I fix this Windows to Go installation in any way?

Comment: Most likely not.

Comment: Yes, by re-creating it on another computer, if you can.

Comment: @harrymc, how? Any guides?

Comment: The same way you created the broken one, but on another computer. Or was the disk created by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

Troubleshooting
then Command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

Then you can try safe mode, or at least get a real error message.

Comment: From where? Install Media aint detecting USB installs.

Comment: Let windows go through "preparing ...." that should get you to a menu you can select Troubleshooting or command prompt.  If all else fails boot from windows installer DVD/USB device once one the main screen SHIFT F8 or SHIFT F10 should get you the command prompt you need.

Comment: Tried both - USB boot doesn't recognize Windows to Go image! And it tried waiting for a day, "Preparing automatic repair" doesn't go away at any cost!

Comment: How about not using Windows Go weirdness.  Download the media creation tool direct from microsoft, and write it to USB.

Comment: I am trying to fix a Windows to Go installation which doesn't boot. As you suggested, I have tried waiting for recovery options, and using install media. In install media, they do not recognize the Windows to Go installation I am trying to fix, that's what I am trying to say!

Comment: How do you define **recognize** regarding Windows to Go?  Can you get to the command prompt from either recovery options, or the windows install media?  If you can get to the command prompt and see the c: drive of your windows installation that is all that is required.

Comment: It doesn't even matter if your C drive is called D,E,F,G or etc in this special mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way for us to guess how your boot USB got corrupted, and so how it
can be repaired.

The best solution would be to re-create the Windows to Go stick in another computer.
I suggest doing so on a computer that is already fully updated with the latest
Windows updates.

As the problem with your pen drive could also be a disk error, I suggest formatting
it before starting. Use a slow format (not quick) to detect and mark bad spots
on the disk. If uncorrectable errors are found on it, I suggest getting a new one.